# Best way to reduce/fold over 2d array in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Emacs lisp has [reduce-vec](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Vector-Lisp-Functions.html). What's the proper way to do this in common lisp, without using loop or reinventing the wheel?

Comment: There's nothing built into CL that treats 2d arrays as sequences of rows. You'll have to write your own loop.

Comment: Emacs's reduce-vec (which you linked to) is reduce for a 1-dimensional vector.  CL's reduce already handles sequences, including 1d vectors.  Do you want to reduce over ((1 2) (3 4)) and see (1 2) and (3 4) as elements, or see 1, 2, 3, and 4 as elements?  That is, do you want to reduce over all the elements, or over the rows of the array?  If the former, then [malisper's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28777457/1281433) is perfect.  If the latter, then @Barmar's comment is right;  you'll need to roll your own.

Comment: Actually, Emacs' reduce-vec accepts a matrix as well, as you can from the link above. @malisper's answer is O(n) space for a reduce (basically iteration) operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use something like the following. It works for arrays of any dimensions.

```
(defun reduce-multidimensional-array (fn arr &rest args)
  (apply #'reduce
         fn
         (make-array (array-total-size arr) :displaced-to arr)
         args))
```

In short, this works by creating a one dimensional array that shares elements with the array passed in. Since reduce works on one dimensional arrays it is possible to reduce the new array.

The function array-total-size returns the total number of elements in the array and the :displaced-to keyword argument causes the new array to share elements with the array passed in (even if they have different dimensions).

Comment: Not a good comment, There's nothing specified in you're question that prohibits this technique. Also you should look at :displaced-to, it does not copy the elements. Also it works for n dimensions unlike your solution